# Getting wrong result while calculating factorials in C.=

Tags: c, factorial

Obviously, this is a [hometask] and a totally newbie question that I'm asking. I tried to figure it out on my own by changing code multiple times but still get wrong results from factorial calculation. 
The idea of the program is to print a table of factorials for the integer numbers from 1 to 10. To get the trick done, my idea was to use nested for and while statements as shown in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    int n, factorial, u;
    u = n;

    printf ("Table to calculate factorials from 1 to 10\n");
    printf ("n                    Factorial to n\n");

    for (n = 1; n <= 10; n= n+1)

    {   

        while (u <= n)
        factorial = n * u;
        u = u - 1;
        printf ("%i                    %i\n", n, factorial);


    }

    return 0;

}
```

However, I am getting wrong results in the console. Guess I messed up with an algorithm to calculate factorials or program logic. I tried changing the code but still get stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

You've actually got several problems, to the point where it's difficult to tell what you're intention was in the first place. `u` is unitialized, the while loop is missing braces, and you're assigning the wrong value to `factorial`.

Here's one way you could fix things.

```
for (n = 1; n <= 10; ++n)
{   
    factorial = 1;

    for (u = 1; u<=n; ++u)
    {
        factorial *= u;
    }

    printf ("%i                    %i\n", n, factorial);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working now. You're correct - I missed the braces and started using u variable before initializing it. Got it now. Thanks!

Comment: If you set factorial to 1 BEFORE the loop, and then multiply by n inside the loop, you don't need a second loop at all. Much simpler.

Comment: @Mats Good point. I was just trying to do things similar to the way it was already written, using the existing variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your original idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)    
{
    int n, factorial, u;

    printf ("Table to calculate factorials from 1 to 10\n");
    printf ("n                    Factorial to n\n");

    for (n = 1; n <= 10; n= n+1)    
    {   
      factorial = u = 1;

      while (u <= n)
      {
          factorial *= u;
          u = u - 1;
      }
        printf ("%i                    %i\n", n, factorial);


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I messed it up with an algorithm for calculating factorials in my original code and (as it stated above) missed the braces. Appreciate your help!